# Creating dynamic content in nancy self hosting

Tags: c#, nancy

I have a standard .NET framework application and I'm trying to make a web front end for it. I'm trying to have nancy render custom content, where i can pass in a model and then i can reference that in the page code, here is the code i am trying to use to do this:

```
public class Server : NancyModule
{
    readonly string main = "WebServer/Pages/main.html";

    public Server()
    {
        dynamic Model = new ExpandoObject();
        Model.username = "blah";
        Get("/", p => View[main, Model]);
    }
}
```

and then in the main.html file:

```
<h1>@username</h1>
```

I was expecting this to show me "blah" as a header, but it is just showing me @username instead.

How can i pass in variables and show them in the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, needed to specify `@Model.username` instead of just `@username`